# Assign value in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two objects : `$scope.objectA` and `$scope.objectB`.
I assign value from `$scope.objectA` to `$scope.objectB` like this:

```
$scope.objectB.value1 = $scope.objectA.value1;
```

then I make `value1` of `$scope.objectB` to `null`;

```
$scope.objectB.value1 = null;
```

My question is why when I assign `$scope.objectB.value1` to `null`, `$scope.objectA.value1` is `null` too. How can I keep value of `$scope.objectA.value1` while changing value of `$scope.objectB.value1`?

Comment: In your code you only use `$scope.objectB`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make copy of object B and assign it to the object A. Use angular.copy function. It will creates a deep copy of source.

For more information [Visit Angular copy doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)

```
$scope.objectA.value1 = angular.copy($scope.objectB.value1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because this is how it works. You make these two variables "bound" together.
If you want to keep value of `objectA`, then use

```
$scope.objectB.value1 = angular.copy($scope.objectA.value1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this can happen only if ObjectA and ObjectB refer to the same object on the heap, i.e. it ObjectA and ObjectB are the same objects

```
$scope['object1'] = {};
$scope['object1']['val'] = {};
$scope['object2'] = {};
$timeout(() => {
  this.$scope['object2']['val'] = this.$scope['object1']['val'];
  $timeout(() => {
   this.$scope['object2']['val'] = null;
      console.log(this.$scope['object1']['val']); // Object {}
    })
});
```

-

```
 $scope['object1'] = {};
    $scope['object1']['val'] = {};
    $scope['object2'] = {};
    $timeout(() => {
      this.$scope['object2']['val'] = this.$scope['object1']['val'];
      $timeout(() => {
       this.$scope['object2']['val'] = null;
          console.log(this.$scope['object1']['val']); // null
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is when you assign `object` to a variable, the assignment will be by reference, so the old and new will be a reference to the original object

[image]

So when you edit an object, you're actually editing the original `object`.

**The solution**

1. Angular: use `object = angular.copy(myObject1)`
2. jQuery: `object = $.extend({}, myObject1);`